# Instrument a .NET assembly in order to capture unit tests

Tags: c#, .net, f#, intercept

I would like to automatically instrument a .NET assembly so that calls to certain functions and the returned results are logged as a means of creating unit tests from whole system tests.

How might this be accomplished?

Comment: This is a pretty broad question and you've tagged it with both C# and F#.  I think this is a question more suited to programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you are describing [Pex](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/), which does support F# (though I've seen posts which indicate it sometimes gets confused with F# vs. C# or VB).

Actually, [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/) sounds like it could be used to achieve something closer to what you are describing.